# Unity RTS Total War Style Click and Drag Unit Formation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working in unity trying to implement the total war style of unit formation width/depth creation with click and drag like seen in this video at about 15 seconds:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aGRzy_PzJQ

I have written some code, but I am getting out of index errors. Here it is so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Formation : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        formationMaker();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        formationShape();

    }

    public GameObject unit;//this is a cube prefab with scale dimensions .45,1.8,.3
    public Transform parent;//this is the parent object of the cubes acting as anchor point
    private Vector3 startClick;
    private Vector3 endClick;
    private float width;
    private List<GameObject> unitsList = new List<GameObject>();
    private int numberOfMen;
    private int rows;
    private int leftOverMen;//was going to use these two to calculate the number of men in the last row and...
    private int lastRowSpace;//...the amount of space needed to center them
    private int count;
    private float manWidth = (float)4.5;


    private void formationMaker()//this makes the formation upon start
    {

        for(int x = -10; x< 10; x++)
        {
            for(int z = -4; z< 4; z++)
            {
                Instantiate(unit, new Vector3(x* .7F, .9f, z*1.0f), Quaternion.identity, parent);
                unitsList.Add(unit);
            }
        }
    }

    private void formationShape()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            startClick = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            endClick = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        //ERROR HERE?
        width = Vector3.Distance(startClick, endClick)/manWidth;//width has to be the width in terms of number of men, but i'm not sure where to get this width
        //ERROR HERE
        numberOfMen = unitsList.Count;
        rows = (int)Mathf.Floor(numberOfMen / width);
        leftOverMen = (int)Mathf.Ceil(numberOfMen % width);
        lastRowSpace = ((int)width - leftOverMen) / 2;
        Debug.Log(rows);
        Debug.Log(width);
        Debug.Log(numberOfMen);


        if (width != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    unitsList[count].transform.position = new Vector3(i * .7F, .9f, j * 1.0f) + startClick;


                    count++; 
                } 
            }
        }
        width = 0;

    }


    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your count not reset to zero,and you should convert width to int to eliminate the error.

PS.Input.mousePosition is pixel coordinates,not world position!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get world position by use Input.mousePosition ( use Raycast instead)
Your width can be zero => (int)Mathf.Floor(numberOfMen / width); can lead to errors

If you still look for solution, you can refer to this code (I edited from your code)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Formation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numberSpawn;
    // Use this for initialization
    private void Awake()
    {
        m_BoxSelected = new BoxSelected();
    }
    void Start()
    {
        //count = 0;
        //formationMaker();
        formationMaker(new Vector3(1, 1, 1), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), 30, numberSpawn);

        //formationMaker3(new Vector3(), new Vector3(-20, 0, -20), 2f, ref unitsList);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {


    }

    public BoxSelected m_BoxSelected;
    public Camera m_MainCamera;
    private Ray m_ray;
    public GameObject unit;//this is a cube prefab with scale dimensions .45,1.8,.3
    public Transform parent;//this is the parent object of the cubes acting as anchor point
    private Vector3 startClick;
    private Vector3 endClick;
    private float width;
    [SerializeField]
    private List<GameObject> unitsList = new List<GameObject>();
    private int numberOfMen;
    [SerializeField]
    private float manWidth = (float)4.5;


    private void formationMaker()//this makes the formation upon start
    {

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++)
            {
                Instantiate(unit, new Vector3(x * .7F, 0f, z * 1.0f), Quaternion.identity, parent);
                unitsList.Add(unit);
            }
        }
    }

    private void formationMaker(Vector3 _StartPos, Vector3 _EndPos, float SizeObj, int _NumberObj)//this makes the formation upon start
    {
        float _width = Mathf.Abs(_StartPos.x - _EndPos.x);
        float _height = Mathf.Abs(_StartPos.z - _EndPos.z);
        int row = 0, col = 0;
        if (_width > SizeObj && _height > SizeObj)
        {
            float dt = _width * _height;
            float _SumCanContain = dt / SizeObj;
            if (_SumCanContain >= _NumberObj)
            {
                // OK
            }
            else
            {
                // kiểm tra xem mảng có đựng vừa số Obj không
                float Temp = Mathf.Sqrt(_NumberObj);
                if ((int)(Temp + 0.5) != (int)Temp) // Phần thập phân lớn hơn 0.5
                {
                    row = (int)(Temp + 1);
                    col = (int)(Temp + 1);
                    _width = (int)(Temp + 1) * SizeObj;
                    _height = (int)(Temp + 1) * SizeObj;
                }
                else
                {
                    row = ((int)(Temp) + 1);
                    col = (int)(Temp);
                    _width = ((int)(Temp) + 1) * SizeObj;
                    _height = (int)(Temp) * SizeObj;
                }


            }
        }
        else
        {
            // kiểm tra xem mảng có đựng vừa số Obj không
            float Temp = Mathf.Sqrt(_NumberObj);
            if ((int)(Temp + 0.5) != (int)Temp) // Phần thập phân lớn hơn 0.5
            {
                row = (int)(Temp + 1);
                col = (int)(Temp + 1);
                _width = (int)(Temp + 1);
                _height = (int)(Temp + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                row = ((int)(Temp) + 1);
                col = (int)(Temp);
                _width = ((int)(Temp) + 1);
                _height = (int)(Temp);
            }
        }

        int cout = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < _height; z++)
            {
                if (cout < _NumberObj)
                {
                    //Instantiate(unit, new Vector3(x * .7F, .9f, z * 1.0f), Quaternion.identity, parent);
                    unitsList.Add(Instantiate(unit, new Vector3(x * .7F, .9f, z * 1.0f), Quaternion.identity, parent));
                    cout++;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    #region Add Funtion
    public int ReverseToOne(int value)
    {
        if (value > 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    private void FormationShapeSquad(Vector3 _StartPos, Vector3 _EndPos, float SizeObj, ref List<GameObject> ListObj)//this makes the formation upon start
    {
        float _NumberObj = ListObj.Count;
        float _width = Mathf.Abs(_StartPos.x - _EndPos.x);
        float _height = Mathf.Abs(_StartPos.z - _EndPos.z);
        int Cols = 0, Rows = 0;
        if (_width > SizeObj && _height > SizeObj)
        {
            float Acreage = _width * _height;
            float _SumCanContain = Acreage / SizeObj;
            if (_SumCanContain >= _NumberObj)
            {
                // OK
                Debug.Log("OK");
                Cols = (int)(_width / SizeObj);
                Rows = (int)(_height / SizeObj);
            }
            else
            {
                // kiểm tra xem mảng có đựng vừa số Obj không
                float Temp = Mathf.Sqrt(_NumberObj);
                if ((int)(Temp + 0.5) != (int)Temp) // Phần thập phân lớn hơn 0.5
                {
                    Cols = (int)(Temp + 1);
                    Rows = (int)(Temp + 1);
                    _width = Cols * SizeObj;
                    _height = Rows * SizeObj;
                }
                else
                {
                    Cols = ((int)(Temp) + 1);
                    Rows = (int)(Temp);
                    _width = Cols * SizeObj;
                    _height = Rows * SizeObj;
                }


            }
        }
        else
        {
            // kiểm tra xem mảng có đựng vừa số Obj không
            float Temp = Mathf.Sqrt(_NumberObj);
            if ((int)(Temp + 0.5) != (int)Temp) // Phần thập phân lớn hơn 0.5
            {
                Cols = (int)(Temp + 1);
                Rows = (int)(Temp + 1);
                _width = (int)(Temp + 1) * SizeObj;
                _height = (int)(Temp + 1) * SizeObj;
            }
            else
            {
                Cols = ((int)(Temp) + 1);
                Rows = (int)(Temp);
                _width = ((int)(Temp) + 1) * SizeObj;
                _height = (int)(Temp) * SizeObj;
            }
        }

        int cout = 0;
        int _dirZ = ReverseToOne((int)(_StartPos.z - _EndPos.z));
        int _dirX = ReverseToOne((int)(_StartPos.x - _EndPos.x));
        float TempWeight = _StartPos.x;
        float TempHeight = _StartPos.z;
        for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Rows; j++)
            {
                if (cout < _NumberObj)
                {
                    ListObj[cout].transform.position = new Vector3(TempWeight, 0f, TempHeight);
                    cout++;
                    TempHeight += _dirZ * SizeObj;
                }

            }
            TempWeight += _dirX * SizeObj;
            TempHeight = _StartPos.z;
        }

    }
    private void FormationLine(Vector3 _StartPos, Vector3 _EndPos, float SizeObj, ref List<GameObject> ListObj)//this makes the formation upon start
    {

        float _NumberObj = ListObj.Count;
        //float _distance = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2 (_StartPos.x, _StartPos.z) , new Vector2( _EndPos.x, _EndPos.z));
        float _distance = Vector3.Distance(_StartPos, _EndPos);
        int Row = 0, Col = 0;
        float _width = 0, _height = 0;
        /*if(_distance > SizeObj)
        {*/
        //Use Default value
        float Temp = Mathf.Sqrt(_NumberObj);
        if ((int)(Temp + 0.5) != (int)Temp) // Phần thập phân lớn hơn 0.5
        {
            Row = (int)(Temp + 1);
            Col = (int)(Temp + 1);
            _width = Row * SizeObj;
            _height = Col * SizeObj;
        }
        else
        {
            Row = ((int)(Temp));
            Col = (int)(Temp) + 1;
            _width = Row * SizeObj;
            _height = Col * SizeObj;
        }
        //Debug.Log("_distance " + _distance + " ; witdh = " + _width, gameObject);
        if (_distance > _width)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Out Wrong _distance "+_distance+" ; witdh = " + _width , gameObject);
            // Use dyamin setRTS
            Row = (int)(Mathf.Ceil(_NumberObj / Row));
            Col = (int)(_distance / SizeObj);
        }
        else
        {
            //Use default Arange => do not change col, row
            // Handle StartPos and EndPpos same Pos (just Click, not drag Mouse)
            if (_distance == 0)
            {
                Vector3 Dir = new Vector3(-1, 0, -1);
                _EndPos += Dir;
            }
        }


        int cout = 0;
        Vector3 TempEndPos = _EndPos;
        Vector3 TempStartPos = _StartPos;
        for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
        {
            Vector3 Dir = _EndPos - _StartPos;
            Dir = Dir.normalized;
            Vector2 VTPT = new Vector2(Dir.z, -Dir.x);
            VTPT = VTPT.normalized;
            Debug.DrawLine(_StartPos, _EndPos, Color.yellow);
            for (int j = 0; j < Col; j++)
            {
                if (cout >= _NumberObj)
                {
                    break;
                }

                ListObj[cout].transform.position = TempStartPos;
                cout++;
                Vector3 _dir = TempEndPos - TempStartPos;
                _dir = _dir.normalized;
                TempStartPos += _dir * SizeObj;
                TempEndPos += _dir * SizeObj;

            }

            if (cout >= _NumberObj)
            {
                break;
            }

            TempStartPos = _StartPos + new Vector3(VTPT.x, 0, VTPT.y) * SizeObj;
            TempEndPos = _EndPos + new Vector3(VTPT.x, 0, VTPT.y) * SizeObj;
            Debug.DrawLine(_StartPos, TempStartPos, Color.red);
            Debug.DrawLine(_EndPos, TempEndPos, Color.green);
            _StartPos = TempStartPos;
            _EndPos = TempEndPos;



        }

    }
    #endregion

    private void formationShape()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //Debug.LogWarning("Click Button Down");
            //startClick = Input.mousePosition;

            RaycastHit hit;
            m_ray = m_MainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            Physics.Raycast(m_ray, out hit, 1000f);
            startClick = hit.point;
            m_BoxSelected.m_baseMin = startClick;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            m_ray = m_MainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            Physics.Raycast(m_ray, out hit, 1000f);
            endClick = hit.point;
            m_BoxSelected.m_baseMax = endClick;

            //FormationShapeSquad(startClick, endClick, 1.5f, ref unitsList);
            FormationLine(startClick, endClick, 1.5f, ref unitsList);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            //formationMaker3(startClick, endClick, 1.5f, ref unitsList);

        }

    }


    void Update()
    {
        formationShape();
    }


    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(m_BoxSelected.m_Center, m_BoxSelected.m_Size);
    }

}




public class BoxSelected
{
    public BoxSelected() { }
    public Vector3 m_baseMin, m_baseMax;
    public Vector3 m_Center
    {
        get
        {
            Vector3 _center = m_baseMin + (m_baseMax - m_baseMin) * 0.5f;
            _center.y = (m_baseMax - m_baseMin).magnitude * 0.5f;
            return _center;
        }
    }

    public Vector3 m_Size
    {
        get
        {
            return new Vector3(
                Mathf.Abs(m_baseMax.x - m_baseMin.x),
                (m_baseMax - m_baseMin).magnitude,
                Mathf.Abs(m_baseMax.z - m_baseMin.z)
                );
        }
    }

    public Vector3 m_Extents
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Size * 0.5f;
        }

    }
}
```

[Solution for FormationShapeSquad and FormationLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyzFh.jpg)

Sorry for my bad English!